# using is vs are

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

Should I say:

> The core of async programming **are** the `Task` and `Task<T>` objects.

or

> The core of async programming **is** the `Task` and `Task<T>` objects.

Is it correct to use is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain subject-verb agreement:

> 1. The **core** of async programming **is** the `Task` and `Task<T>` objects.
> 2. The **cores** of async programming **are** the `Task` and `Task<T>` objects.

Simply put, how many cores are there? If just one, then it's singular; if two, then it's plural.